# Ini-parser doesn't read whole file

Tags: c#, wpf, ini

I have WPF application used with [ini-parser](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser) library that i used to read and change values inside of ini file.

Issue that i have with this library is that it doesn't read whole file when i open it, for example original ini file have 16629991 characters and when opened with ini-parser function `iniData = iniParser.ReadFile(IniFile);` it reads only 11701685 characters.

Also after saving data to ini file, ini get shrinked from 16,248 kb to 11,230 kb.

Example code i am using to change values in ini file

```
foreach (var Section in ItemsList)
{ 
    iniData[Section]["1"] = "ccc"; // replace with ccc
}
iniParser.WriteFile(IniFile, iniData); // write to opened ini file
```

Configuration

```
iniParser.Parser.Configuration.AllowDuplicateKeys = true;
iniParser.Parser.Configuration.AllowDuplicateSections = true;
iniParser.Parser.Configuration.AssigmentSpacer = "";
```

Is there any limit to file size that can be set in configuration option that i didn't find in documentation or something else can cause this issue ?

Here is [zipped ini file](https://mega.nz/#!WVpzBSSb!_8zoZT4GRA4dxX0G5rVM0vCswHqZHyghoBimu7DzaHw)

Comment: Why do you have such a large ini-file? Why do you not use a database?

Comment: @Silvermind ini file is from one old game, if i change its content or size except key 1 under specified sections, then i don't see any items in game anymore.

Comment: @Mario Have you considered to create own implementation for parsing this large file instead of using a library? `ini` file usually are quite small. You can also try to customize the behavior, like is stated in [wiki](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/wiki/Configuring-parser-behavior)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i didn't consider to make my own function for parsing, since all in this library works except opening, reading whole file. But if i don't find any solution i think i will need to make my own. I also tried many others and win api, but problem with them is that every line in foreach writes, that makes it very slow since there is around 3000 items to rename, it takes about few minutes to rename all, and ini-parser takes less than a minute.

Comment: You could try to split the file and later merge it with ini parser. Are you sure the file is not broken, tried to set `Configuration.SkipInvalidLines=true`?

Comment: @Rekshino yes i am sure 100% file is not broken since when i open it and write, read with win api, all is good, just it is slow since it must use `ini.Write()` for each item in foreach loop that make process very slow.